# Split one row to multiple rows in html while using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a code that looks like this :

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

  void Button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    // Set the properties of the HtmlTable with the
    // user selections.
    Table1.Border = Convert.ToInt32(BorderSelect.Value);
    Table1.Height = HeightSelect.Value;
    Table1.Width = WidthSelect.Value;

  }

</script>

<html>
<head>
   <title>HtmlTable</title>
</head>
<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <h3>Html table for standards</h3>

      <table id="Table1" 
             style="border-width:1; border-color:Black"
             runat="server">

         <tr>
            <th>
               Standard
            </th>
            <th>
               File name
            </th>
            <th>
               Pass/Fail
            </th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               Cell 1
            </td>
            <td>
               Cell 2
                <br />
                Cell 9
                    <br />
                Cell 18
                    </td>
            <td>
                    pass<br />
                fail<br />
                pass</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               Cell 4
            </td>
            <td>
               Cell 5
            </td>
            <td>
                pass</td>
         </tr>

      </table>

      <hr />

      Select the display settings: <br /><br />



      Border:
      <select id="BorderSelect" 
              runat="server">


         <option value="2">2</option>

      </select>

      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      Height:
      <select id="HeightSelect" 
              runat="server">

         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="100">100</option>
         <option value="150">150</option>
         <option value="200">200</option>
         <option value="250">250</option>

      </select>

      &nbsp;&nbsp;

      Width:
      <select id="WidthSelect" 
              runat="server">

         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="200">200</option>
         <option value="250">250</option>
         <option value="300">300</option>
         <option value="350">350</option>

      </select>

      <br /><br />

      <input id="Button1" type="button" 
             value="Generate Table"
             onserverclick="Button_Click" 
             runat="server"/>

   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The output that comes up is this :
[image]

My issue is : I want that all the rows corresponding to cell 1 ( i.e. Cell 2, 9,and 18) to be split into different rows (having boundary) similar to what we have in excel sheets.

Please help. I am new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: for this you totally make the table dynamically from c# end.

Comment: @NazirUllah can you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cell 2,9 and 18 must be in different rows and cell 1 must use rowspan="3"

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

```
<table>

     <tr>
        <th>
           Standard
        </th>
        <th>
           File name
        </th>
        <th>
           Pass/Fail
        </th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" >
           Cell 1
        </td>
        <td>
           Cell 2

        <td>
                pass</td>
     </tr>
 <tr>

        <td>
           Cell 9

        <td>
                fail</td>
     </tr>
  <tr>

        <td>
           Cell 18

        <td>
                pass</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           Cell 4
        </td>
        <td>
           Cell 5
        </td>
        <td>
            pass</td>
     </tr>

  </table>
```

and the style

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hT9vP/255/

Comment: I do not want to make changes to cell 1, I want to add boundary around cell 2,9, and 18 to make them look like excel sheets.

Comment: In your code cell 2,9 and 18 are in the same cell...the way to split them and have the effect that you want is what I suggested...have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried this. It does not work.
<tr>
 <td rowspan="3">cell 1</td>
            <tr> Cell 2 </tr>

              <tr>  Cell 9 </tr>

              <tr>  Cell 18 </tr>
                    </td>
            <td>
                    pass<br />
                fail<br />
                pass</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               Cell 4
            </td>
            <td>
               Cell 5
            </td>

Comment: @SheenaAgrawal check the full answer above